# What is the purpose of indentation in a poem?

Tags: poetry

For example, in this poem, entitled *[Remember](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/45000)*, by Christina Rosetti:

> Remember me when I am gone away,
>         Gone far away into the silent land;
>         When you can no more hold me by the hand,
>   Nor I half turn to go yet turning stay.
>   Remember me when no more day by day
>         You tell me of our future that you planned:
>         Only remember me; you understand
>   It will be late to counsel then or pray.
>   Yet if you should forget me for a while
>         And afterwards remember, do not grieve:
>         For if the darkness and corruption leave
>         A vestige of the thoughts that once I had,
>   Better by far you should forget and smile
>         Than that you should remember and be sad.

Comment: First of all  I'm not sure you have provided a text of the poem that has the original spacing, or indentation. Second, spacing–of which indentation is part–is used to communicate. What it communicates might have to be interpreted by the reader. Assuming you find a copy of this poem that has the original indentation, what purpose do you think the indentation serves? Edit: it seems the source link provided by @Adam does refer to a proper layout of the poem.

Comment: However, I think this question is off-topic because it is about literary criticism and spacing in poems.

Comment: Maybe you realize that there is a Literature stack exchange? https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

> In poetry, a **[stanza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanza)** is a grouped set of lines within a poem,
>   usually set off from other stanzas by a blank line **or indentation**.
>   ..
>   The stanza in poetry is analogous with the paragraph that is seen in prose; related thoughts are grouped into units.

This becomes clearer when you look at a different indentation of the same poem, as can be seen [here](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/remember):

[image]

Pay attention to which lines rhyme with each other.